# Как добавить ветку из другого действующего проекта?

Tags: mercurial

Есть репозиторий hg, некоторого проекта (библиотека). Она находится в разработке. Создается проект для фронта со своим репозиторием. Можно ли подключить в новом проекте ветку из репозитория библиотеки, чтобы держать ее в актуальном состоянии? И сразу второй, можно ли создать ветку в которой лежат ток определенные файлы , вроде ветки дистрибутивов?

Comment: А при при чём тут гит?

Answer (score 0):

- Нет, но главное - неправильно сформулирована задача: сразу техническое решение в стиле гит-боев, вместо формулировки бизнес-требований "надо чтобы...". Тогда и решение может быть
- Да, но не нужно - потому что "вроде ветки дистрибутивов" это **тэги** в любом бранче